# How to clear the data stored after logging out in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, reset, logout

Is there any way to clear all the data stored on the memory after logging out in such a way that it looks like the condition when the application is run for the first time?

In my Winform project, there are different user levels that have different access to different forms and different controls.
After I click the log out button, the previous settings remain.

Is there any way to reset everything back to zero without having to set the all the setting  of each form and every control ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the answer.

It was very simple.

```
Application.Restart();
```

It shuts down the application and starts a new instance immediately.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to manually nullify static variables if any are being used to store data on logout click.
To delete cookies:

```
foreach (string cookieFile in Directory.GetFiles(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Cookies)))
{
    try
    {
        File.Delete(cookieFile);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it for ASP.net? I am looking for an answer for C# WinForm application.